# Classification of isometry groups

Tags: geometry, manifolds, isometry

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold. Are there results on the classification of possible isometry groups of $M$? Does the classification of three-manifolds lead to such a classification of isometry groups, for example?

Comment: Every compact Lie group is an isometry group of some compact Riemannian manifold: Saerens, Rita; Zame, William R., The isometry groups of manifolds and the automorphism groups of domains, Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 301, 413-429 (1987). ZBL0621.32025. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87070/can-every-lie-group-be-realized-as-the-full-isometry-group-of-a-riemannian-manif I don't know the answer for noncompact groups.

Comment: I proved the compact dimension 0 case of the Saerens-Zame theorem in Trans AMS, Feb. 1976.)